# Ruby & ERB - creating a base64 value from unknown String?

Tags: ruby, erb

I have a requirement to create a base64 value from a variable that I don't know the value of. I was going to use

```
["String...@VARIABLE"].pack('m')
```

but my issue is that I don't know what the value of the variable is, and it may include special characters, including apostrophes. I have looked into encoding options, but from what I understand, it will create a different String, so a different value after base64 transformation.

What's the correct approach to get it working?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Base64` module to encode:

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'base64'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> Base64.encode64("any string, may include 'apostrophes'")
=> "YW55IHN0cmluZywgbWF5IGluY2x1ZGUgJ2Fwb3N0cm9waGVzJw==\n"
```

Comment: And it supports encoding any binary string too.

Comment: Will it support all characters, including quotation marks?

Comment: Yes, it supports even binary strings, as Gabor mentioned. So all characters.